# Databricks repos - unable to use dbutils.notebook.run with absolute path

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I'm unable to get an absolute path working with `dbutils.notebook.run()`. Using the absolute path with `dbutils.fs.ls(with "file:/Workspace/Repos/user_email/Datalake/databricks/models/notebook")` returns a FileInfo object. Running the same filepath string with `dbutils.notebook.run(path)` does start running a job, however with an error that the notebook was not found. The error includes a path which is the combination of the relative filepath (of the notebook from which I run the `dbutils.notebook.run()` command) concatenated with the path I to the referenced notebook.

Seems that `dbutils.notebook.run` is not able to access notebooks absolute with repos?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/Workspace/Repos/user_email/...` is the path on the driver machine, that is local to your cluster node.  It works with `dbutils.fs.ls` because it works with files of different types.  This path is a special replication of actual notebook/file that resides at path `/Repos/user_email/...` inside the workspace

On other hand, `dbutils.notebook.run` works with notebooks in the workspace, not with files, so you need either to specify that path as `/Repos/user_email/...`, but it's better to use relative paths, because it's more portable, for example, if someone else will use your code from the repository.

Comment: I'm using os.cwd() etc to make the absolute path change, the above path is an example.
It worked however skipping the workspace part, thanks!